# A function to do "try... except..."

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

I want to put a "try... except..." into a function so that my code is shorter because it is used multiple times.

Make this work:

```
def whiletry(x):
    while 1:
        try:
            x
            break
        except:
            time.sleep(0.25)

whiletry(driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="j_list_card"]/ul/li/h3/a').click())
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? Your function does exactly the same as `def whiletry(x): return x`

Comment: @ThomasSchillaci sorry I posted the wrong code could you check again?

Comment: "Make this work" SO is a QA site, not a code writing service

Comment: @Andrew in Python, expressions are fully evaluated before they are passed in to a function. So, you could pass in a function when called that simply returns your expression

Comment: You should be more careful about a bare except that doesn't notify the user when it catches. If you have a bug in your code you won't be able to see it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
def whiletry(func):
    while 1:
        try:
            return func()
        except:
            time.sleep(0.25)

def click():
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="j_list_card"]/ul/li/h3/a').click()

whiletry(click)
```

The usage can also be equivalently written as:

```
whiletry(lambda: driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="j_list_card"]/ul/li/h3/a').click())
```

Note the `lambda`.

Comment: thanks, the 'lambda' and changing `x` into `x()` inside the function made it work

Answer (score 3):

If you are testing with Selenium and want to wait for something to appear on webpage, [*waits* may help you.](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html)

In my experience custom try-excepts and infinite loops in Selenium may lead to maintenance problems. Standard Selenium wait would look like that:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as expected

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
element = wait.until(expected.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="j_list_card"]/ul/li/h3/a')))
element.click()
```

Comment: Or `driver.implicitly_wait(10)` to be able to just write the rest of the code normally.

Comment: This is good, but you might want to `wait` until the element is clickable, though.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this should work for your use-case:

```
def do_this():
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="j_list_card"]/ul/li/h3/a').click()

try:
    do_this()
except:
    time.sleep(0.25)
```